# Why is dcast not working in reshape2?

Tags: r, reshape2

This paper that was published for reshape package (Wickham 2007) gave this example:

```
library(reshape2)
ffm <- melt(french_fries, id = 1:4, na.rm = TRUE)

dcast(ffm, variable ~ ., c(min, max))
```

Similarly, this doesn't work in reshape2 but appears to work in Wickham 2007

```
dcast(ffm, variable ~ ., summary)
```

However the cast function is giving an error. How can I get function to work?

Comment: The [paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v21/i12/paper) is using `reshape` rather than `reshape2` and, more importantly, it uses the `cast` function rather than the `dcast` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v21/i12/paper) is for the `reshape` package, not the `reshape2` package. You have also not reproduced the example as it was written. It should be:

```
library("reshape") # not explicit in the paper, but implied since it is for the reshape pacakge
ffm <- melt(french_fries, id = 1:4, na.rm = TRUE)
cast(ffm, treatment ~ rep, c(min, max))
```

Note that the function call is `cast`, not `dcast`. That change was one of the major changes between the two packages. Another was the dropping of multiple aggregation at the same time as reshaping as this was considered to be better handled by the `plyr` package. If you use the `reshape` package (which is still available from CRAN), the examples work.

Comment: Do you know why ability to use functions like min(), max() and summary() were dropped in reshape2?

Comment: @luciano you can still use those functions, but only one at a time. If you're doing multiple aggregation, you're probably better off using plyr.